# how to access objects gotten from service in the component?

Tags: angular, service, typeerror

When I tried to access atoms using 'this.atoms' in the searchAtoms, it returns "TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined". I am thinking atoms are all set because *ngFor is working well. There is some hidden logic behind subscribe? If someone knows about this, could you give some clues? And, also another question, when I defined getAtoms method with a parameter, atom name value gotten from input field in the atom.service.ts like this.service.getAtoms(newAtom). But I get "A parameter proerty is only allowed in a constructor implementation". I think I can't use this way. Could you anybody recommend a desirable way for this?

app.component.ts

```
import {Component} from 'angular2/core';
import {Router} from 'angular2/router';
import {AtomService} from './service/atom.service';
import {Atom} from './datatype/Atom';

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    template: `<br>
    <input #atomname value='atom1'>
    <button (click)=searchAtoms(atomname.value)>Search Atoms</button>  
    <br><br>
    <ul>
        <li *ngFor="#atom of atoms">
            {{atom.id}} - {{atom.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>`,
    providers: [ConceptService]
})


export class AppComponent {

    atoms: Array<Atom>;

    constructor(private service : AtomService) {

    }

    searchAtoms(newAtom: string) {
        console.log("searchAtoms\t" + newAtom);
        if (newAtom) {
            this.service.getAtoms(newAtom).subscribe(data => this.atoms = data);
            console.log(this.atoms.length);
        }
    }
}
```

atom.service.ts

```
import { Injectable }     from 'angular2/core';
import { Http, Response, URLSearchParams, Headers } from 'angular2/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Atom} from '../datatype/Atom';

@Injectable()
export class ConceptService {

  constructor(private http: Http) {
    this.http = http;
  }

  getAtoms(private newAtom: string) {
    return this.http.get('api/atoms.js')
    .map( (responseData) => {return responseData.json()})
    .map( data => {
        let results:Array<Atom> = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < data.result.length; i++) {
            results.push(new Atom(data.result[i].id, data.result[i].name));
        }
        return results;
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `Http` service returns an `Observable` and you subscribe to it. This is an asynchronous operation but you are trying to access the data before it arrives from the server. If you move your `console.log` inside of your `subscribe` callback it will work.

```
this.service.getAtoms(newAtom).subscribe(data => {
  this.atoms = data;
  console.log(this.atoms.length);
});
```

For your second question you just need to drop the `private` keyword.

```
getAtoms(newAtom: string) { }
```

Comment: Additional question, :) is there anyway I can call the method inside subscribe? I tested it by defining console.log(this.atoms.length) as another method named printTest(). I could not call printTest, it says that "ReferenceError: printTest() is not defined". I think it does make sense. Ultimately, I would like to paginate those atoms, so I need some manipulations on atoms array. Actually, I am thinking to slice a limited number of atoms by delegating it to the paging service(paging.service.ts). Do you have some recommendations for this task? I really appreciate it again.

Comment: Did you call it like `this.printTest()`? It should work. But yeah, I would recommend you to move pagination logic to a service.

Comment: :) working well. I am really sorry but if a user clicks to see other page, not from the data after getting Observable through subscription, I think I have to have duplicate atoms, isn't it right? After second thought, I become a little confused. If you are possible, I will expect your answer. If it isn't, I will study more. Thank you so much.

Comment: I think that's out of the scope of this question as there are different ways to architecture your components and routes; and I don't know exactly what you mean with duplicate atoms. So you can accept this answer, try to solve the other problem by yourself and if not post a new question. ;)

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thank you so much for your kind explanation!!